# 500 internal error only when running from windows (7)

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, internal-server-error

Problem: the program is facing a `500 Internal Error` when accessing a website using this code: (I work with PyQt)

**Happens only on my *windows* box (WIN7) and not on my linux (ubuntu 12.04 LTS) fyi they are different computers (but on the same LAN)**

```
def sendBearer_req(self):
    request = QNetworkRequest()
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"))
    request.setRawHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
    request.setRawHeader('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % cons_enc)

    self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
    if self.network_manager.receivers(SIGNAL("finished")) > 0:
        self.network_manager.finished.disconnect()
    self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._request_finished)        

    self.network_manager.post(request, self.urlencode_post({'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}))

def _request_finished(self, reply):
    if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
        # request probably failed
        print(reply.error())
        print(reply.errorString())
        print("retrying")
        self.sendBearer_req()
    else:
        self.sendBearer(reply)
```

Output:

```
299    
Error downloading URL - server replied: Internal Server Error    
retrying
```

where URL is the page url.

---

- I tried it with many URLs in case the problem was really in the server itself but it's not.
- `cons_enc` is valid (b64 encoded string)

**How to fix it?** and if you know why in ubuntu it works?

Answer (score 0):

Status code 299 is non-standard and the [Twitter API Error Code Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) does not list it. Likely the cause is not related to this stub of code

QNetworkReply [defines](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/network/access/qnetworkreply.h) code 299 as "unknown error", maybe it's a Qt bug.

As a suggestion, try using a proper [Twitter API for Python](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Comment: it is for an assignment that forbids me using a Twitter API. and the error is 500 not 299 (299 is the `QNetworkReply` error code and not the Twitter error code)

Comment: @Dan, different build/version?

Comment: Solved it, problem was mine I accidently runned it on windows with Python3 and it was intended for Python2.7

Comment: I can't believe PyQt does not check Python version before starting up!

Comment: @esseks: What? Why would PyQt check python version? PyQt runs under Py2 and Py3 just fine. And you can write a single code that would run under both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found, apparently I runned it accidently on Python 3.3 on windows and it was built for Python 2.7 (which was used in the linux box).

Maybe PyQt should check that before starting up!